# Javascript BST recursion. How to remove a node class with "this" reference?

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

My problem is really simple. I'm trying to remove a node from my tree with the following structure. How could I delete the node that meets my condition? Basically I just want to set it to null so its parent just points to null.

This is not the actual code, but explains the concept. Basically every node in the tree is a new BST.

```
class BST{
  constructor(val){
    this.val = val;
    this.right;
    this.left;
  }

  insert(val){
     // find correct node insert in appropriate child
     this.left = new BST(val) // or this.right
  }

  someRecursiveFn(){

    if(this.val === 'removeMe') {
      // REMOVE NODE
      // this = null // illegal
      // this.val = null // same problem...I still have the class prototype & it's right & left children

      return
    }

    this.left.someRecursiveFn();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think it's possible unless you would store the instance of the object in the object itself (like with the singleton pattern). Since the class itself won't know where it is stored.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-2-delete/

Comment: Could you check the children of `this` rather than  checking `this` itself? `if(this.left.val === 'removeMe') this.left = null;` and the same for `this.right`?

Comment: Both the singleton and checking the children would work. But I was just curious if it was possible to keep this clean, while avoiding passing parameters to the function. Seems like it's not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to georg for coming up w the idea. It's pretty simple really. Just use an assignment operation on the recursion call.

```
class BST{
  constructor(val){
    this.val = val;
    this.right;
    this.left;
  }

  insert(val){
     // find correct node insert in appropriate child
     this.left = new BST(val) // or this.right
  }

  someRecursiveFn(){

    if(this.val === 'removeMe') {
      // REMOVE NODE
      // this = null // illegal
      // this.val = null // same problem...I still have the class prototype & it's right & left children

      return null;
    }

    this.left = this.left.someRecursiveFn();

    return this
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve that "elegantly" would to be introduce a special terminal object which will be used instead of `null` to designate an absence of a value.

```js
class Zero {
    insert(val) {
        return new Node(val)
    }
    remove(val) {
        return null
    }
}

let zero = () => new Zero()

class Node {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val
        this.L = zero()
        this.R = zero()
    }
    insert(val) {
        if(val < this.val) this.L = this.L.insert(val)
        if(val > this.val) this.R = this.R.insert(val)
        return this
    }
    remove(val) {
        if(val === this.val)
            return zero()

        if(val < this.val) this.L = this.L.remove(val)
        if(val > this.val) this.R = this.R.remove(val)
        return this
    }
}

//

tree = new Node(5)
tree.insert(2)
tree.insert(6)
tree.insert(3)
tree.insert(8)
tree.insert(4)
tree.insert(7)


document.write('<xmp>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</xmp>')

tree.remove(4)

document.write('<xmp>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</xmp>')

tree.remove(8)

document.write('<xmp>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</xmp>')
```